# Variable values become null after clicking on second window opened from first window's view model

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, viewmodel

The software I am working on has a `Mainwindow` in which there are several buttons that open new windows. Each of these should have a `ViewModel`.

In the `MainWindowViewModel` the software creates some data, eg `ProList` and `summariesData`. One of the buttons in the main window that opens a new window is "Show Bars" button. In the `MainWindowViewModel`, I have connected Show bars button with `ICommand` to a method that instantiates the new window. I use code-behind Show Bar buttons to open the new window.

```
Dim wndSummariesObject = New WndSummaries
wndSummariesObject.Show()
```

In the same method, I instantiate the `ShowbarsViewModel` to pass the data it needs to work with.

```
WndSummariesViewModelObject = new WndSummariesViewModel(_ProfileList, 
    SummariesWndData) With {
        .ProfileList = ProList,
        .SummariesWndData = SummariesData
    }
```

It shows that the constructor transfers the data into the `ShowBarsViewModel`, but the problem is when I click on one of the buttons in the Show bar button to operate its task, I lose all the variables' values that were instantiated and transferred before from the `MainWindowViewModel`!

Where am I making the mistake?

------- Update

It has the same behavior(Making null) when I want to send the instance of the first ViewModel as a parameter of the constructor of the second ViewModel.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All I see is a couple of constructor calls. I have absolutely no way of knowing what's in the rest of your code.

Comment: I am trying to pass the data that is created in the MainwindowViewModel to another Windows' ViewModel. The constructor passes the data into the second ViewModel, but when I press a button in the new window, those data become null!. Please help me. I don't know what else I need to include.

Comment: Please click the link in my above comment and read it. Nobody can help you based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in Xaml I was setting an instance of the ViewModels. Even though I was setting the parameters in the constructor, but the second ViewModel was using the one that was created in the Xaml mistakenly.

```
<Window.Resources>
     <ViewModels:WndSummariesViewModel x:Key="WndSummariesVM"/>
     <viewModels:ProViewModel x:Key="ProViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
```